# Verifying a transaction is legit

Tags: solana

I have a frontend and a backend, where the workflow looks like this:

- Frontend sends a transaction
- Frontend waits until the transaction is successful
- Frontend sends the transaction id to backend
- Backend verifies if the request is not malicious, and the transaction is valid

The reason I have a backend is because my project requires further processing after a transaction is successfully made.
How does one properly verify if a transaction is legit or not?
I'd like to prevent malicious actors from somehow tricking the backend by faking a transaction.
Is it enough to simply use the `getTransaction` rpc method to see if a valid result is given?

Comment: Send the signature to the backend from the frontend and have the background verify it is a valid chain entry?

Comment: Echoing what Frank said, what could be malicious about it? Any program on Solana should do the correct checks to reject a transaction if it is trying to do something malicious

Comment: By verifying if the chain entry is valid, is [isBlockhashValid](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#isblockhashvalid) what I should be looking at?